# Accessing ASMX Webservice using Digest Client Authentication Method (ASP.NET)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asmx, impersonation, digest-authentication

Accessing an AMSX webservice that is using Digest authentication, I have configured my website's web.config file as follows:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="SEWebServiceSoap" >
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly" >
            <transport clientCredentialType="Digest" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://localhost:00000/SEWebService.asmx" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SEWebServiceSoap" contract="SEWS.SEWebServiceSoap" name="SEWebServiceSoap" />
    </client>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="impersonationBehavior">
          <clientCredentials>
            <!--<windows allowedImpersonationLevel="Impersonation" allowNtlm="false" />-->
            <httpDigest impersonationLevel="Impersonation" />
          </clientCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

But I keep getting this error message:

> The impersonation level 'Identification' was specified, yet HTTP
>   Digest authentication can only support 'Impersonation' level when used
>   with an explicit credential.

I have searched about that a lot, but no information found. Any clue?